# Efficiently picking random indexes from a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I'd like to pick at random out of the indexes of those elements of a numpy array that meet a condition.  My arrays are typically 2D, a few million elements total; the condition is computed over the whole array, and only relatively few elements (< a percent) come out true.  I need to pick *one* element where the condition is true, at random.  Because of the use of the data, the random choice has to be unbiased (every true element picked with the same probability) and I only pick one per array on each pass (so no reuse of any calculations).

Slow code which does the right thing by building a list of all candidate indexes explicitly:

```
# prepare sample data
img = np.zeros((2048,2048), dtype=bool)
for n in range(10000):
    i, j = np.random.randint(img.shape[0]), np.random.randint(img.shape[1])
    img[i,j] = True

def pick(img):
    indexes = np.argwhere(img)
    k = np.random.randint(len(indexes))
    return indexes[k]

pick(img) # around 8ms
```

This seems to take a stupidly long time to pick one element out of 10000.  The culprit is, of course, np.argwhere() which is where most of the time is spend.  I don't need the whole list this returns; I just need one element from a random shuffle of that list, and can stop the calculation early at that point.

How do I do the same thing, but faster?

P.S. The elements may be clustered - it is entirely possible for all of the true values to be in one corner of the array.  So any speedup which relies on dividing areas probably won't work :)

Comment: Do you actually need to pick a random index, or do you just need the value? How big is `img` in your test case? I agree 8ms sounds incredibly long for `np.argwhere()`

Comment: @alkasm Yes random index where the value is true, just as in the example.  The 2048x2048 size and 0.2% true values as in the example is fairly typical for real data - although percentage of true values may be much higher eg 10% in some corner cases (which run much slower).

Comment: `np.unravel_index(np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(img)), img.shape)` seems to do a lot better, there might be better yet tho

Comment: @alkasm Good speedup, around 5x.  Could you please explain how it works?  Feel free to post as answer, I have a feeling it would be hard to do much better.

Comment: Yea, I'm trying some other stuff but no dice. I imagine there's some index tricks (i.e. `np.ix_`) that could be useful here but I'm not super familiar with that set of numpy functionality, I'll look around for a bit and expand on the comment if I can't find anything else in a few minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a significant, but not quite an order of magnitude speedup with:

```py
np.unravel_index(np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(img)), img.shape)
```

Here `np.flatnonzero` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html)) gives the linearized index into the array of non-zero entries:

```py
>>> np.flatnonzero(img)
array([    276,     548,    1053, ..., 4193808, 4194060, 4194198])
```

And then `np.random.choice` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)) to choose just one of those values (using `flatnonzero` instead of `nonzero` lets me avoid having to choose one index per axis, and instead just use a single index):

```
>>> np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(img))
3123039
```

Then we just need to convert between this linearized index and the multidimensional index, which can be achieved with `np.unravel_index` ([docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html)):

```
>>> np.unravel_index(3123039, img.shape)
(1524, 1887)
```

---

With `pick` defined as in your example and `pick2` as:

```py
def pick2(img):
    return np.unravel_index(np.random.choice(np.flatnonzero(img)), img.shape)
```

the `timeit` module shows >5x speedup:

```py
>>> timeit(lambda: pick(img), number=100)
1.208479189008358
>>> timeit(lambda: pick2(img), number=100)
0.17817635700339451
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably much more efficient to randomly subsample, in fact, I see a ~300x speedup on the example.

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

# prepare sample data
img = np.zeros((2048,2048), dtype=bool)
for n in range(10000):
    i, j = np.random.randint(img.shape[0]), np.random.randint(img.shape[1])
    img[i,j] = True

def pick(img):
    indexes = np.argwhere(img)
    k = np.random.randint(len(indexes))
    return indexes[k]

def pp(img,maxiter=100,batchsize=1000):
    imf = img.reshape(-1)
    for i in range(maxiter):
        idx = np.random.randint(0,imf.size,batchsize)
        pick = np.argmax(imf[idx])
        if imf[idx[pick]]:
            return np.unravel_index(idx[pick],img.shape)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("no luck")

print('OP',timeit(lambda:pick(img),number=100)*10,'ms')
print('pp',timeit(lambda:pp(img),number=100)*10,'ms')

# sanity check
samples = np.array([pp(img) for _ in range(200000)])
histo = np.bincount(np.ravel_multi_index((*samples.T,),img.shape))
assert (histo.nonzero()[0] == img.reshape(-1).nonzero()[0]).all()
print(np.bincount(histo)[1:])
```

Sample run:

```
OP 14.76260277966503 ms
pp 0.045300929923541844 ms
[  0   0   0   0   0   2   5  15  24  59  96 176 241 394 513 661 796 812
 908 922 822 751 648 548 457 365 265 155 141  88  55  29  26   9   5   1
   2   1]
```

The last output is (starting from 1) the number of True positions that were picked that many times out of 200000 trials, i.e. there are 2 positions that were picked 6 times, 5 that were picked 7 times etc. Expected is something that peaks at 20 and looks roughly brll shaped.